# group consecutive equal values and count up

Tags: python, pandas

The df:

```
a b  
0 1
0 3
0 3
0 1
1 1
1 2
1 4
```

I would like to group by a and count up the equal consecutive rows in a group:

```
a b c
0 1 1
0 3 2
0 3 2
0 1 3
1 1 1
1 2 2
1 4 3
```

I tried:

```
df['c'] = df.b.groupby([df.a, df.b.diff().ne(0).cumsum()])
```

which gave me a type error:

```
Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: just edited. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

In your case , that is factor

```
s=df.b.diff().ne(0).cumsum().groupby(df.a).transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0])+1
Out[276]: 
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    1
5    2
6    3
Name: b, dtype: int32
df['c']=s
```

Or

```
df.b.groupby(df.a).apply(lambda x : x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
Out[277]: 
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    1
5    2
6    3
Name: b, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
s = df.ne(df.shift()).any(1).astype(int)
df['c'] = s.groupby(df['a']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  1  1
1  0  3  2
2  0  3  2
3  0  1  3
4  1  1  1
5  1  2  2
6  1  4  3
```